# txt.replace </blockquote> in textarea js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I give up! I looked at many different answers. I've tried many different ways and nothing works. I want to change the `</blackquote>` tag to `<br />` or a new line in the textarea. Alternatively,  change to some other character, because later I can replace another character in PHP to `<br/>`. How to do it?
Working example for easy understand here: https://jsfiddle.net/jsf88/rb3xp7am/35/

```
<textarea id="comment" name="quote" placeholder="quote" style="width:80%;height:200px;"></textarea>
<section class="replyBox" style="width: 100%;"><br/>
  <a href="#napisz" class="quoteMsg"> [ click for quote ] </a>
  <div class="replyMsg">

    <blockquote>this is a quote for comment&#128526; </blockquote><br />
    "X" -- HERE I want BR_TAG or new line in textarea after click 'quote' &#128528;

  </div>
</section>

$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('.quoteMsg').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').text();    
    //txt = txt.replace('</blockquote>', '<br/>');   
    //txt = txt.replace(/<\/(blockquote)\>/g, "<br/>");
    //txt = txt.replace(/blockquote*/g, '<br/>');
    //txt = txt.replace(/(.*?)<\/blockquote>(.*?)/g, ' xxx ');
    txt = txt.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, '<br/>')//NOT WORKING!!
    
    txt = txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');//working great
    console.log(txt);
    $("textarea[name='quote']").val($.trim('[quote]' + txt + '[/quote]'));
  });
});
```

To make it funnier, another example with changing the blackquote tag to br works without a problem. Why? can someone explain it?

```
//OTHER EXAMPLES WHERE CHANGE </BLACKQUOTE> to <br/> WORKING GOOD... WTF?!
string = ` <blockquote>this is a quote for comment&#128526; </blockquote><br />"X" -- HERE I want BR_TAG or new line in textarea after click 'quote' &#128528;`;

string = string
.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, ' <br /> ');//but here working! ;/
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you recover text with text function `('.replyMsg').text()` but in that case you will have the text but with no html tag like `<blockquote>` so first you will have to recover the html to have the blockquote tag
   `var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').html();`
2. the br tag is not interpreted in textarea so you have to change it by a new line character
3. don't forget to remove opened bloquote tag to get the expected result

`txt = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');`

```js
$('.quoteMsg').click(function() {
  var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').html();
  txt = txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
  txt = txt.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, '\n');
  txt = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');

  console.log(txt);
  $("textarea[name='quote']").val($.trim('[quote]' + txt + '[/quote]'));
});
```

```css
blockquote {
  background-color: silver;
}

.replyMsg {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.quoteMsg {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="comment" name="quote" placeholder="quote" style="width:80%;height:200px;"></textarea>
<section class="replyBox" style="width: 100%;"><br/>
  <a href="#napisz" class="quoteMsg"> [ click for quote ] </a>
  <div class="replyMsg">

    <blockquote>this is a quote for comment&#128526; </blockquote>

    "X" -- HERE I want BR_TAG or new line in textare a after c lick 'quote' &#128528;

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: YES! I was missing the .html tag... damn! Thank you for the explanation. I hope you will have a good day! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem in your code was how you were adding the event listener to the `ready` event. Being it something invented by jQuery, and not a native event, the correct way to do it should be as of now (v.3.3.1 the version I used in this demo) `$(document).ready(()=>{/*code here*/})`.

As a further reference:
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of
> jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. Note that if the DOM becomes
> ready before this event is attached, the handler will not be executed.

***But...*** it's not perfectly clear how did you wish to transform your text before setting the value of the textarea. So I just better factored your logic so that you have some clear steps:

- grabbing the blockquote element text content and trimming it (being the origin)
- applying the transform newline to whitespace (with the regex that I left untouched)
- build the final string as a template literal that will include the quote content, the meta tags wrapping it, AND anything else you wish to add like for example a new line (`\n`) that in this example is exacerbated by a text following it.

There's a hint in your words that put me in the position to say something superflous but still deserving an attempt: the value of a inner text is just plain text and doesn't render html content. So the `<br>` itself would remain as you read it and wouldn't have any rendering effect on the textarea content. That's why I focused my demonstration on putting a newline with the escaping sequence. It works both on double quoted strings and template literals: `"\n"` `` `\n` ``

#### Further notes

It seems the original approach of processing the blockquote html was preferred. It's worth saying that it was ***appearently*** a terrible strategy for several reasons:

- It grabs the blockquote content as html despite that's not how it's
  rendered on the page.
- It takes the effort to consider the whole outerHTML removing the
  wrapping blockquote tags instead of fetching directly the innerHTML.
- It adds the newline as newline instead of embedding it as `<br>` so
  at this point I ask myself if the content in the textarea was
  supposed to be encoded html or not.. and the added br would then
  belong to something meta?
- It's harder to deal with in case you want to further customize the
  string processing

***But...*** maybe there's something I didn't get and I'm doing weak assumptions.

```js
//since you are using the ready event with jquery, that's the correct syntax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quoteMsg').click(function() {

    //grabs the text content of the blockquote element (trimming it)
    var quoteTextContent = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').text().trim();
    
    //performs the transform already in place in your code.. replacing newlines with white spaces
    quoteTextContent = quoteTextContent.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' '); //working great    
    
    //builds the string to set the textarea value with, using a template literal
    //here you can add anything you want.. like a new line but that's just an example
    const encoded = `[quote]${quoteTextContent}[/quote]\nand something following to show the new line happening`;

    console.log(encoded);
    $("textarea[name='quote']").val( encoded );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="comment" name="quote" placeholder="quote" style="width:80%;height:200px;"></textarea>
<section class="replyBox" style="width: 100%;"><br/>
  <a href="#napisz" class="quoteMsg"> [ click for quote ] </a>
  <div class="replyMsg">
    <blockquote>this is a quote for comment&#128526;
    <br>
    Having new lines also ... since you perform a regex transform newline=>whitespace
    </blockquote><br />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for answers. The problem was a missing .html tag.
This script work for me almost perfect for quoting few times:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('.quoteMsg').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').html();    
  txt = txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
    txt = txt.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
    txt = txt.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
    txt = txt.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    txt = txt.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    txt = txt.replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
    txt = txt.replace(/<br>/g, "");
    txt = txt.replace(/<hr>/g, "[hr]");
    //txt = txt.replace(/<hr>/g, "\n");
  txt = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');
  txt = txt.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, '[hr]');
    txt = txt.replace(/[hr][hr]/gi, "");//not working ([][])
    txt = txt.replace(/[hr][hr]/gi, "[hr]");//not working ([[hr]][[hr]])
    console.log(txt);
    $("textarea[name='quote']").val($.trim('[quote]' + txt + '[/quote]\n'));
  });
});
```

The problem here is I dont know how to change dubble [hr][hr] for nothing, because this `txt = txt.replace(/[hr][hr]/g, "");` not working, so would be cool for more explain about. One more time big thanks for answers! this function .replace is not as intuitive as in PHP.

EDIT: ahh.. I think is not possible to delete this dubel, because I extra insert it two times. Nvm. I will find and del this dubel in PHP.